# directed graph is strongly connected

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

An undirected graph G is given as an input. 
I need to tell whether it is possible to direct each edge of G so that the resulting
directed graph is strongly connected.

What algorithm should I use?

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to determining whether the graph is connected and [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory))less (where a "bridge" is an edge such that, if you removed it, some vertices would become disconnected).

I trust you'll have no difficulty figuring out whether the graph is connected. For determining whether it's bridgeless, you can use [Tarjan's bridge-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)#Tarjan's_bridge-finding_algorithm), which will find a bridge if and only if one exists.